# Does everywhere positive definite Hessian imply bijective gradient?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

If $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is strictly convex, i.e. its hessian is everywhere positive definite, does that imply its gradient is bijective? To ensure the well-definedness of the Légendre transform, which is usually used on s.c. functions, I need the gradient to be bijective, so as to be sure that for any $p\in\mathbb R^n$ there exists one and only one $x\in\mathbb R^n$ for which $p=\nabla f(x)$...

Comment: you might want to check out this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1372692/does-positive-definite-hessian-imply-the-jacobian-is-injective/1372726. Obviously injective does not implies surjetive...

Comment: Partial duplicate, indeed. But it would be nice to have things all in one place, wouldn't it?

Comment: if $a = b$ then $h^T a = h^T b$ for any $h$. By negation you get $h^T a \ne h^T b$ implies $a \ne b$. As for your question, consider $f(x) = \exp(x)$.

Comment: Your example seems to say surjectivity is not implied, but then the transform cannot be defined on all $\mathbb R^n$! Is that so? So is the transform perhaps defined only on the codomain of the gradient? It must be so.

Comment: Legendre transformation is always defined for convex functions. I have no idea where you need strict convexity. Also notice, that strict convexity does not imply positive definite hessian (only the reverse direction is correct)

Comment: I was actually defining a strictly convex function as one with everywhere p.d. hessian.

Comment: that is rather uncommon.

Comment: I guessed so. AFAIK the only place this is done is [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/tex/legendre.pdf), which is my main reference for Légendre transforms, [though deprecable it may be](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457974/how-does-this-prove-that-hessian-is-positive-definite#comment2968988_1457974).

Comment: you could try Wikipedia or google or just post another question.

Comment: I did post another question for an issue on that pdf, the link is in the comment. I won't google further, because I risk to find somehing that opens other problems and I'm rather fed up of finding one problem every two secs while writing my thesis. And with problems from the thesis I have FLOODED Math.SX :).

Comment: or you would just find a better reference. The reference you posted is just badly written.

Comment: Still, the proofs convince me, besides the question linked to above. And that is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody closed or answered this, I will self-answer and self-accept, so as to make it answered.

That the Hessian be everywhere p.d. implies the gradient is injective, as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1372726/135592). Basically, the proof uses Taylor expansion with integral form for the remainder, then using p.d.-ness to prove the remainder is always strictly positive.

$f(x)=e^x$ has everywhere p.d. Hessian (i.e. everywhere strictly positive second derivative) but is surely not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f$ of class $C^1$ and strictly convex: $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y)<\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$ when $x\neq y$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

**Injectivity:** look at $t \mapsto f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)$ for $t \in [0,1]$. This function is strictly convex. Writing $f'(0)<f'(1)$ gives that $\nabla f(x_1)\neq \nabla f(x_2)$.

**Surjectivity:** This does not hold in general. It is enough to have a sublinear/linear growth in one direction. The exponential is an easy example. $x \mapsto \sqrt{1+x^2}$ is another example.

On the other hand, if the function $f$ has super-linear growth towards infinity, $f(x)/|x|\to \infty$, then by definition,
$$ \min_{x \in \Bbb{R}^d}f(x)-x\cdot p$$
has a unique solution $x(p)$ for a given $p$ (minimization of a strictly convex function which is infinity at infinity). This solution verifies $\nabla f(x(p)) = p$. Since this can be done for every $p$, the gradient is surjective in this case.